# Why does selecting text and then hitting the delete key on my IBM Model M keyboard confuse Gnome/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, ps2

I picked up a second hand IBM Model M "clicky" keyboard (series 52G9658) and connected it to the PS/2 port of the "HP Z400 Workstation" here at work (this model M variant has an integral PS/2 cable.) I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with the latest updates and Gnome 2.30.2.

```
$ uname -a
Linux tp-dev-01 2.6.32-31-generic-pae #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 20:00:13 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Whenever I hold down shift and use the arrow keys to select some text on the screen (either in a web form, in gedit, in Eclipse, anywhere) and then press either the delete or backspace keys, I can't click with the mouse anymore! Attempting to select any menu items fails; clicking in another text box (attempting to click in Chrome's address bar for example) doesn't work, alt-tab doesn't work.

Fortunately, if I click on apps in the "task bar" (or whatever Gnome calls it) making my VMWare virtual machine active, then click around in a Windows instance for a bit and then click back to Gnome, everything goes back to normal.

Does anyone have any idea how this could possibly be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, turns out this one was a case of User Error. There are 2 PS/2 ports on the back of this machine and the keyboard works perfectly when I [plug it into the other one](http://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/89q1/wronghole.307.html).

<sub>In my defense they're not labelled :-(</sub>

Comment: are they colour coded? ;p one's green, the other's purple, and its a miracle at all that it even worked - green is for mice and purple for keyboards

Comment: They're colour coded, but the Model M's plug is grey—and really, I've got better things to do than remember the colour coding on a 20 year old port spec. If it hadn't worked at all it would have been the first thing I'd tried. But as it _mostly_ worked, it didn't occur to me I was completely wrong.